# What position a strongest/weakest player should play?

Tags: dota-2

Let's say a team of Dota consist of 4 equally skilled players and one player which is twice as good as his teammates.

Will the position of that player effect the team performance ? If so, what the position the best player should play ?

And the same question in reverse, what position that player should play if he is only half skilled compared to his teammates ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would put the strongest player mid, as the outcome of the midlane usually dictates the mid-game. The mid-game for me is after the laning phase, when people start going for objectives (such as towers, roshan or the bounty rune). If your team wins the midlane, that means that the enemy mid-player is forced out of his lane, which gives you/your team access to their mid tower and the two bounties. You 'secure' the river in a way, and this is also where you have access to roshan, the (bounty) runes, and potential easier ganks to the sidelanes. Finally, most played mid heroes scale very well into this midgame, and having a good player have more gold and levels over the other midplayer makes them a huge threat to the side lanes (where the carries are).

I would put a significantly lower skilled team member on a support. In the current meta (7.19, duo-lanes) where there is a scaling/carry hero and a support hero in both sidelanes for each team, I would put this team member on the offlane support. In the case of a trilane, I would let him play the second support. What I mean with that is that they should buy more expensive support items (Force Staff, Urn of Shadows, Glimmer cape) and occasionally wards, and let my equally skilled team member be the full support that keeps on warding etc. This way, you take away the pressure of have everything fall on your less skilled team member to help your main carry in the safelane, and just let him play his hero and focus on that. I'd suggest a hero with a stun, as they have a reliable and easy way to help out the carry in that lane. Finally, you can have your other (good) support help out your less skilled team member by suggesting ward placements or organizing ganks.

I would not let my less skilled team member play either carry or mid, as these require to take advantage of space to farm and get more gold and then utilize that gold well to buy the correct items for the situation and this is something that less skilled players seem to lack in most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is so broad! and depends to many factors! So, I start by asking some questions:
*What do you mean by strongest/weakest player?*
A player may be strong on play carry heroes or at playing a specific hero at a specific position and lane!
A player may be strong on play a hero at a specific position but also weak with it vs a counter hero! or a combination of heroes!
A player may be strong at *Last-Hitting* or *Denying* or *Both* or *Saving other heroes* or *Pushing* or *warding* or etc.

**Step 1:**
As a coach, you need to rank your players by some attributes that included to your game, So, at first find those attributes or indices for each position(1-5) then weight them after that weight each one for each player (you can weight them by [AHP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_hierarchy_process)). Now you know which player is strongest/weakest in each position.

**Step 2:**
Hero picks are so important, that some bans may make your strongest player so weak as its best heroes bans or some counter heroes picked. So, at ban phase you need to ban those counters or by picking some heroes prepare yourself to pick that specific hero.
I should say please read about your other-side team also.

**Step 3:**
Write some strategies for yourself then use them! some strategies can be:

- When you make a team for ***mid-game win***; so use strongest player as mid-lane carry and weakest player as off-lane roaming -with escape ability- support.
- When you make a team for ***late-game win***; so use strongest player as safe-lane carry and weakest player as off-lane support.
- When they make a team ***with some counter heroes***; use a good player or strongest player as a roamer support -like earth spirit- to help your lanes or help to break their combo, and weakest player at safe-lane support.

Consider that team performance is not important, just think about winning the game! Many win games had a low *Net worth*, *Come-Back* is real and also with really far *Kills-Deads*!
All of above are beginning steps to be a coach! -HTH ;)

Answer (score -2):

If you're new to the game you shouldn't worry about the position as your enemies are going to be same level as you and you won't be stomped (usually) in a game, negating you a fair game where you can learn the mechanics.

Anyway, when playing with a team where everyone is better than you, in order to not to be a burden for the team, the weakest player should never go alone in a lane, as that makes the lane lost since the begining and can create a difficult snowball to handle later.

So, if going to safe lane (assuming a normal game with top, mid, jungle and duo) I would say carry is the safest role for the team.

Why not go support?

Well, being unable to negate creeps, control the enemy, ward the map, stack jungle camps and having your build not growing because you're lacking gold could make that player less useful than playing carry.

When playing carry he can miss some creeps, but he does not need to worry about anything else than farming and staying alive. Carries do not usually initiate fights, play safe and as long as the game lengthens he would help the team with his damage. So he would be useful in the end.

Now, when talking about the strongest player, it becomes more difficult. 

If having a weak player in the team he could go with him in lane to compensate, but it would be difficult for the duo to win the lane and create advantage. So I would choose to go mid lane, as it gives you the chance to move faster between lanes and help your team if needed. Most mid picks are usually powerfull mages with high damage in early-mid game, making it easy for a good player to create advantage and help his team where they're losing.